# apache nutch don't crawl website

Tags: solr, web-crawler, nutch

I have installed the apache nutch for web crawling. I want to crawl a website that has the following `robots.txt`:

```
User-Agent: *
Disallow: /
```

Is there any way to crawl this website with apache nutch?

Comment: How would i set Protocol.CHECK_ROBOTS false in nutch-site.xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In nutch-site.xml, set protocol.plugin.check.robots to false

OR

You can comment out the code where the robots check is done.
In Fetcher.java, lines 605-614 are doing the check. Comment that entire block

```
      if (!rules.isAllowed(fit.u)) {
        // unblock
        fetchQueues.finishFetchItem(fit, true);
        if (LOG.isDebugEnabled()) {
          LOG.debug("Denied by robots.txt: " + fit.url);
        }
        output(fit.url, fit.datum, null, ProtocolStatus.STATUS_ROBOTS_DENIED, CrawlDatum.STATUS_FETCH_GONE);
        reporter.incrCounter("FetcherStatus", "robots_denied", 1);
        continue;
      }
```

Comment: How would i set  Protocol.CHECK_ROBOTS false in nutch-site.xml

Answer (score 2):

You can set the property "Protocol.CHECK_ROBOTS" to false in nutch-site.xml to ignore robots.txt.

Comment: how i can do it? (set Protocol.CHECK_ROBOTS" false)