# Nutch Crawling not working for particular URL

Tags: java, web-crawler, nutch

I am using apache nutch for crawling. When i crawled the page `http://www.google.co.in`. It crawls the page correctly and produce the results. But when i add one parameter in that url it does not fetch any results for the url `http://www.google.co.in/search?q=bill+gates`.

```
solrUrl is not set, indexing will be skipped...
crawl started in: crawl
rootUrlDir = urls
threads = 10
depth = 3
solrUrl=null
topN = 100
Injector: starting at 2013-05-27 08:01:57
Injector: crawlDb: crawl/crawldb
Injector: urlDir: urls
Injector: Converting injected urls to crawl db entries.
Injector: total number of urls rejected by filters: 0
Injector: total number of urls injected after normalization and filtering: 1
Injector: Merging injected urls into crawl db.
Injector: finished at 2013-05-27 08:02:11, elapsed: 00:00:14
Generator: starting at 2013-05-27 08:02:11
Generator: Selecting best-scoring urls due for fetch.
Generator: filtering: true
Generator: normalizing: true
Generator: topN: 100
Generator: jobtracker is 'local', generating exactly one partition.
Generator: Partitioning selected urls for politeness.
Generator: segment: crawl/segments/20130527080219
Generator: finished at 2013-05-27 08:02:26, elapsed: 00:00:15
Fetcher: Your 'http.agent.name' value should be listed first in 'http.robots.agents' property.
Fetcher: starting at 2013-05-27 08:02:26
Fetcher: segment: crawl/segments/20130527080219
Using queue mode : byHost
Fetcher: threads: 10
Fetcher: time-out divisor: 2
QueueFeeder finished: total 1 records + hit by time limit :0
Using queue mode : byHost
Using queue mode : byHost
Using queue mode : byHost
fetching http://www.google.co.in/search?q=bill+gates
Using queue mode : byHost
Using queue mode : byHost
Using queue mode : byHost
Using queue mode : byHost
Using queue mode : byHost
Using queue mode : byHost
Using queue mode : byHost
Fetcher: throughput threshold: -1
Fetcher: throughput threshold retries: 5
-finishing thread FetcherThread, activeThreads=8
-finishing thread FetcherThread, activeThreads=7
-finishing thread FetcherThread, activeThreads=1
-finishing thread FetcherThread, activeThreads=2
-finishing thread FetcherThread, activeThreads=3
-finishing thread FetcherThread, activeThreads=4
-finishing thread FetcherThread, activeThreads=5
-finishing thread FetcherThread, activeThreads=6
-finishing thread FetcherThread, activeThreads=1
-finishing thread FetcherThread, activeThreads=0
-activeThreads=0, spinWaiting=0, fetchQueues.totalSize=0
-activeThreads=0
Fetcher: finished at 2013-05-27 08:02:33, elapsed: 00:00:07
ParseSegment: starting at 2013-05-27 08:02:33
ParseSegment: segment: crawl/segments/20130527080219
ParseSegment: finished at 2013-05-27 08:02:40, elapsed: 00:00:07
CrawlDb update: starting at 2013-05-27 08:02:40
CrawlDb update: db: crawl/crawldb
CrawlDb update: segments: [crawl/segments/20130527080219]
CrawlDb update: additions allowed: true
CrawlDb update: URL normalizing: true
CrawlDb update: URL filtering: true
CrawlDb update: 404 purging: false
CrawlDb update: Merging segment data into db.
CrawlDb update: finished at 2013-05-27 08:02:54, elapsed: 00:00:13
Generator: starting at 2013-05-27 08:02:54
Generator: Selecting best-scoring urls due for fetch.
Generator: filtering: true
Generator: normalizing: true
Generator: topN: 100
Generator: jobtracker is 'local', generating exactly one partition.
Generator: 0 records selected for fetching, exiting ...
Stopping at depth=1 - no more URLs to fetch.
LinkDb: starting at 2013-05-27 08:03:01
LinkDb: linkdb: crawl/linkdb
LinkDb: URL normalize: true
LinkDb: URL filter: true
LinkDb: internal links will be ignored.
LinkDb: adding segment: file:/home/muthu/workspace/webcrawler/crawl/segments/20130527080219
LinkDb: finished at 2013-05-27 08:03:08, elapsed: 00:00:07
crawl finished: crawl
```

I already add the code

```
# skip URLs containing certain characters as probable queries, etc.
-.*[?*!@=].*
```

Why this happens? can fetch the urls if i add parameter? Thanks in advance for your Help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nutch crawler obeys robots.txt and if you see robots.txt located on http://www.google.co.in/robots.txt you will find that /search is disallowed to crawl.

Comment: is it anyway to allow the search?

Comment: Not unless you write some thing custom to do that. However it will violate google TOS

Comment: but in this(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11842913/apache-nutch-dont-crawl-website) they told to crawl by disable the robots

Comment: As far as I know, not obeying robots.txt can get you in trouble. It is definitely not advisable for production systems

Comment: thank u abhinav. do u know how to set this property protocol.plugin.check.robots?

Comment: I am afraid I never did so.