# Nutch error "QueueFeeder finished: total 0 records. Hit by time limit :36"

Tags: apache, web-crawler, nutch

I have about 17000 urls in my urls/seed.txt file. But When I start my crawler(apache Nutch), after job generation, it gives following message

QueueFeeder finished: total 0 records. Hit by time limit :36

and then display -finishing thread FetcherThread0, activeThreads=19 etc. And crawl 0 page.
What is this problem , can anyone guide me?

Comment: What value do you have in the configuration parameters: `fetcher.timelimit.mins` and/or `fetcher.timelimit` ?

Comment: What version of Nutch? In 2.2.1 then `fetcher.timelimit==-1` there is not possibility of being "hit by time limit" (http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/nutch/tags/release-2.2.1/src/java/org/apache/nutch/fetcher/FetcherReducer.java?view=markup#l706). Are you sure `fetcher.timelimit` == -1? Let me check one thing...
Ok: what value does `fetcher.timelimit.mins` have? (and the version of Nutch)

Comment: value of fetcher.timelimit.mins= -1 and version is 2.2.1

Comment: What value for those two configuration options do you see in the actual job sent? You will find it in the Hadoop UI at :50030, in any job where it says `Job File: hdfs://hostname:8020/tmp/hadoop-hadoop/mapred/staging/hadoop/.staging/job_<id>/job.xml`. I had the same issue but with `fetcher.timelimit.mins`=120 and clocks not in sync in my nodes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Nutch Crawling not working for particular URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16766169/nutch-crawling-not-working-for-particular-url)

Comment: @Shafiq Did you solve the problem?

Comment: No, I could not solve it.